# Use of request parameter in view functions

Tags: python, django, request

```
def choice(request):
    return render(request,'LoginPage/choice.html')
```

This is a sample view function from my views.py file. What's the use of the request parameter in the function call? Can it be used to keep a record of the user logged in when surfing the website? I'm really new to django. Please help

Comment: Yes it holds all kind of information, but this question is "too broad" so I flagged it. Please read the documentation which explains a lot of things really well. There are tons of sites and tutorials dedicated to django.

Comment: I need a documentation or tutorial specifically for using this request parameter. And please, not the one on the django website, I cannot understand that one. I need one with a sample code to explain it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr-tAL6iXY8, to start ...

Answer (score 0):

[From docs on render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render),

> ## `request`
>
> The request object used to generate this response.

If you have setup `django.template.context_processors.request` in template settings (which is done by default), every RequestContext will contain a variable request, which is the current HttpRequest.

The `request` variable which is an HttpRequest contains data about the current request. Which can be accessed through the attributes.

**For example,**

#### In views.

In views, the request can be accessed as,

```
def choice(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        ... # Do something for logged-in users.
    else:
        ... # Do something for
```

anonymous users.

### In template.

In templates you can use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` (if auth context processor is setup)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1>Hi Welcome back</h2>
{% elif %}
    <h1>Hi please login</h2>
{% endif %}
```

Full list of attributes are documented here on the [documentation for HttpRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example I have in my project showing how the request argument may be used to keep a visit count

```
def about(request):
    if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
        print("TEST COOKIE WORKED!")
        request.session.delete_test_cookie()
    visitor_cookie_handler(request)
    visits = request.session['visits']
    context_dict = {'visits': visits}
    print(request.environ) # Other data that you can access through the request argument
    print(request.user)
    return render(request, 'rango/about.html', context_dict)
```

And the visitor_cookie_handler, which also takes the same request as argument

```
def visitor_cookie_handler(request):
    # Use COOKIES.get() to retrieve a specific cookie
    # All cookie values are returned as strings
    visits = int(get_server_side_cookie(request, 'visits', '1'))

    last_visit_cookie = get_server_side_cookie(request,
                                               'last_visit',
                                               str(datetime.now()))
    last_visit_time = datetime.strptime(last_visit_cookie[:-7],
                                        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # If it's been more than a day since last visit..
    if (datetime.now() - last_visit_time).days > 0:
        visits += 1

        request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
    else:
        visits = 1
        request.session['last_visit'] = last_visit_cookie

    # Update/set the visits cookie
    request.session['visits'] = visits
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `request` for some thing like : **`post`** and **`get`** request from **htm forms** or ***`session`*** you want to set .

Follow **this link** too khow more :

[django request parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/)